# Spring Data findById vs Join Query performance

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a @OneToMany relation between an Entity say Class with Student. Now for each class there can be atleast 100 students. This is how my relationship with Student is defined in Class entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "classDataEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<StudentDataEntity> studentDataEntities;
```

Just to check the performance of fetching class by ID (PK) we use two methods

1. Optional findById(ID id); // with fetchType Eager with Students
2. create a new method in repository with @Query joining the two tables in classId

We are calling both methods from the same service class method , e.g

```
@Transactional
public ClassDataEntity fetchClassEntity(Long classId){
    ClassDataEntity classDataEntityJOined  = repo.fetchClassWithStudents(id);
    ClassDataEntity classDataEntity  = repo.findById(id);
}
```

My understanding is with lot of Students , the join should perform better since its less call to DB , hence less network calls. But in the above case we are seeing  findById performing much better

Is it because the data with the id is already in session? Also when are Hibernate sessions created and destroyed when invoked via Crud Repositories

Comment: Can you turn on sql logging to see how man queries are run for each option?  The session should be created with each transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's because the data is already in the persistence context. If you remove `@Transactional` you should see that two queries are executed because then the persistence context would not be shared (unless you have open-session-in-view enabled in spring).